# Why doesn't su have its setuid bit set?

Tags: rooting, root-access, supersu

I checked the permission of `su` with `ls -l`, and found it doesn't have the `setuid` bit set. This is different from common desktop Linux. Is there any reason behind this difference?

The `su` binary was installed using supersu on an experimental Nexus device with factory ROM.

Comment: Related question at Unix.SE: [How does Magisk on Android work as su without setuid and capabilities?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462605/27672).

Comment: Detailed explanation: [What special privileges "/system/xbin/su" does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer at Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406170/27672). Instead of the `setuid` bit, the binary has some [capabilities](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) set via file's extended attributes. The particular caps are of interest are `CAP_SETUID` and `CAP_SETGID`.